# How to automatically running daily SQL script (Oracle) using python?

Tags: excel, oracle, automation, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to automatically run daily SQL script (Oracle) using python?
- Is that possible to do?
- If possible, How can I export the result from the query to excel by automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `python` `cron` to execute script every day please refer the documentation https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab.

use `cx_Oracle` in `python`. Below is the documentation for that:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/OOW11/python_db/python_db.htm

this link will help you in order to create your desired script.

Once you get the result in database then you can either use oracle scheduler job or batch scheduler jobs from os to execute your oracle query result into excel:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222209/how-to-automate-csv-exports-of-queries-in-pl-sql-developer-oracle

Comment: Thanks you for your solution.